# How to use implode function in foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to display a ",(comma)" in between each records fetched from the db.eg:location1,location2,location3 etc

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
<?php 
    //var_dump($volunteer_panel_location);
    echo "<tr>"
       . "<td class='col-xs-4'>Interview Location </td>"
       . "<td>";
    foreach ($volunteer_interview_location as $vlocations)
    {
        echo "{$vlocations->location}";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>"
       . "<tr>"
       . "<td>Panel Location </td>"
       . "<td>";
    foreach ($volunteer_panel_location as $plocations)
    {
        echo "{$plocations->location}";
    }
    echo "</td>"
       . "</tr>";
?>
</table>
```

I tried this,but the records repeated

```
$pp=array();
foreach ($volunteer_panel_location as $plocations)
{
    $pp[]=$plocations->location;
    echo implode(",",$pp);
}
```

Comment: Google it, php's own page tells you how to use implode.

Comment: What speak against `implode()` http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php

Comment: @Ann Just implode your array outside the foreach loop, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$locations = [];
foreach ($volunteer_panel_location as $plocations)
{
    $locations[] = $plocations->location;
}
echo implode(",",$locations);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar='';   
for ($i=0; $i <count($data) ; $i++) {
    $ar[]=$data[$i]->id;
}
$rt=implode(',',$ar);
echo $rt;
```

replace `$data` to your data.

`$ar` is an array.

I suggest calling implode outside of foreach function.

Comment: You define a string and then use it as an ``array``,  why ``$data[$i]->id`` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo implode(",",$volunteer_panel_location);
```